# self.PresentingViewController.title is [null]

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, title

I have a modal Detail View Controller and I need to get the title of the ViewController that presented it. I have the following code attached to a button action in the modal controller, but it always returns null:

```
NSLog(@"presnetingViewController.title=%@",[self presentingViewController].title);
```

Log:

```
presnetingViewController.title=(null)
```

I set the title of the presenting view controller in the Storyboard and I can get the title programatically from a method in the presenting view controller.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you present you modal view controller from a navigation controller?

Comment: I have a TabBarController as my root controller, then two tab views that each use the same View Controller class to control tables. I need to know which tab view presented the modal.

Answer (score 3):

Use
    NSLog(@"presnetingViewController.title=%@",[self presentingViewController].navigationItem.title);

If your presenting view controller is on a navigation controller stack use

```
NSLog(@"presnetingViewController.title=%@",((UINavigationController *)[self presentingViewController]).topViewController.navigationItem.title);
```

Comment: I ended up just passing it in the segue. Thanks!